# Is it possible to monitor heading / course after triggering CLRegion?

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocation, clregion

I mean i would like this to happen :

1 - monitor exiting a region
2 - when the region triggers , i would like to know ex: if the user exiting this region is going North or South and trigger an specific notification based on that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can start monitoring for heading updates using `CLLocationManager`.

```
 if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {
       manager.headingFilter = 5
       manager.startUpdatingHeading()
}
```

then the `CLLocationManager`'s delegate will provide heading updates via:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
```